# ember-pikaday losing a day

Tags: ember.js, datepicker, pikaday

I'm trying to use ember-pikaday, but I'm having issues with it not displaying the correct date. Every time the date it displays, its the previous date of the actual date. For example if the date is 04/06/2016, it displays 04/05/2016. Below is the code that I am using, I have noticed though that if I replace value with placeholder, then the date does display correctly, just not in the right format, i.e. 2016-04-06. What's going on here?

```
{{pikaday-input id="effectiveDate" name="effectiveDate" class="form-control textCenter" format="MM/DD/YYYY" value=model.effectiveDate firstDay=0 disabled=isDisabledDate}}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in an https://ember-twiddle.com/ or github repo?

Answer (score 0):

This is because it uses your local timezone by default when creating a new Date object. The addon supports working with UTC, try setting useUTC=true on the component.